# Mysql Join issue and i want this result

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have two tables 1 and 2 or i need this result (**see my image 1**)  using Join in mysql also see my Query for verification

```
  SELECT c.`id`, 
         c.`name`, 
         COUNT(*) AS `totalcount`
    FROM categories c INNER JOIN subcategories sc 
            ON c.`id` = sc.`cat_id`
GROUP BY c.`id`
ORDER BY c.added_date DESC
```

I want this result

[image]

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Help are definitely appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`

try this:

```
SELECT a.`id`, a.`name`, count(b.`cat_id`) as totalCount
FROM categories a LEFT JOIN subcategories b
        on a.id = b.cat_ID
GROUP BY a.`id`
ORDER BY a.added_date desc
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` -

```
SELECT    c.`id`, c.`name`,
          COUNT(sc.cat_id) AS `totalcount` 
FROM      categories c LEFT JOIN
          subcategories  sc 
ON        c.`id` = sc.`cat_id`  
GROUP BY  c.`id` 
ORDER BY  c.added_date DESC;
```

A demo is [here](http://ideone.com/MjhF6).